# Downloading files from another site and add into zip

Tags: php, zip

There are a few csv files hosted on another website n i'm trying to retrieve them and package into a zip file to download. Zipping seems to work but the package is always empty. Any help is very much appreciated... This is in PHP by the way.

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "test114.zip";
$numParts = count($file_names);
if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) 
{
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}



$file="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&d=9&e=25&f=2012&g=d&a=0&b=3&c=2000&ignore=.csv"; 
$filedata = fopen ($file, "r"); 
$contents = fread($filedata, filesize($file)); 
$zip->addFile($filedata, "file1");
fclose($filedata);  


$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\".zip;");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the extension from this line:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\";");
```

You already set the filename extension on second line (of code).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make sure that you have write permissions in your current working directory

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "test114.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) 
{
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}


$file="http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&d=9&e=25&f=2012&g=d&a=0&b=3&c=2000&ignore=.csv"; 
$filedata = file_get_contents($file);
$zip->addFromString( "file1", $filedata);
$zip->close();

$path = getcwd()."/".$filename;

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary ");
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($path);


unlink($filename);

exit;
?>
```